# Please help identify aircarft

Tags: identification, aircraft

[image]

Can anyone help identify this aircraft. I was told it is a Northrup design. Looks pre WWII to me.
Al

Comment: Looks about right. Here is a link to a three-view drawing of the XFT http://www.aviastar.org/pictures/usa/northrop_xft.gif

Comment: @Comintern post it as an answer, maybe?

Answer (score 4):

The closest visual match I can find is the [Northrop XFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_XFT), an unsuccessful prototype. That particular wheel spat design is fairly distinctive and indicative of late 20s to early 30s, but as a hand-carved model it might be more representational than based off a specific model.

Comment: Could be a P36 with the wheels down.